# Postfix postmap: fatal: bad string length 137 >1:

Tags: postfix

Help, i get this error on postfix, what thats mean?

```
postmap: fatal: bad string length 137 > 1: recipient_delimiter = + mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp_local_destination_recipient_limit = 300 local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
```

and, how to fix this?i use in centos.

thank you

Comment: It appears you have concatenated multiple lines from the config file.  Use `postconf -d mailbox_transport` and so on, for each of the config options to see what they should look like.  `-d` is for the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron says, you have concatenated the lines. To concatenate, you have to start the line by a space (or maybe a tab, I don't know).

Check the configuration, the lines commands must start at the first column.